# Why does this C++ program with OpenMP not scale?

Tags: c++, openmp

I am baffled by the fact that the following program executes always in the same amount of time regardless of the number of threads I'm using with OpenMP:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    std::vector<int> v(1000000000, 1.0);
    auto t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
#pragma omp parallel for
    for(int k = 0 ; k < v.size(); ++k)
    {
          v[k] *= 2;
    }
    auto t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto dt = std::chrono::duration<double, std::nano>(t2 - t1).count();
    std::cout << dt<< std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Before anyone asks: yes, OpenMP is working on my machine; the code above came from a library I'm working on and I consistently observe speedups with OpenMP. I am using gcc 5.4.0 and compiling with `-O3`, and running on an Intel i5-4210U.

Does the execution time scale with the number of threads for any of you?

Here is the full gcc command: `g++ -O3 -std=c++11 x.cpp -fopenmp`

Comment: `v` is larger than the CPU cache, so you are probably memory bandwidth limited.  The cache is really good at serial access, adding more threads introduces random access to main memory.  Plot a graph with 1,2 etc threads look for diminishing returns

Comment: Since your code makes no use of `v` after the loop your compiler might be smart enough to optimise the loop away entirely.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: that's not happening because the execution time is clearly scaling linearly with the length of `v`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: I have two cores with hyper-threading, so 4 logical cores in total. I tried with 1, 2, 3 and 4 threads (using `OMP_NUM_THREADS=N` when executing the test).

Comment: @pap42 the test code does not spend enough time doing CPU intensive work, what you are really testing is how fast you can get data into and out of the CPU / main memory.  Once you bottleneck on the memory bus adding more threads will not improve performance.

Comment: @RichardCritten: Brilliant! That for sure explains not only this issue, but also many others I'm seeing here -- if instead of merely multiplying each vector element by a constant, I do a CPU-heavy operation on it, the scaling then becomes visible. You are right -- memory access is the bottleneck here.

Comment: Typically, on a mobile/desktop system memory bandwidth will be saturated by slightly more than one active thread, whereas on server systems you need many more active threads to saturate memory. Regarding your question, please **always include the specific performance measurement results**. Do not sum it up like "always in the same amount of time", as this hides very valuable information from the people reading your question.